# How to move UL tags inside of a div to form a menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a shopping menu in my html code,
Here is the simple piece of html I am working with so far

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
    .category-list
    {
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
    body {background-image: url("images/background.gif");}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="category-list">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1-1</li>
        <li>Item 1-2</li>
        <li>Item 1-3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 2-1</li>
        <li>Item 2-2</li>
        <li>Item 2-3</li>
        <li>Item 2-4</li>
        <li>Item 2-5</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 3-1</li>
        <li>Item 3-2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Item 4-1</li>
        <li>Item 4-2</li>
        <li>Item 4-3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you take a look at the image below,

[image]

The image on the left is what is displaying at the moment,
the image in the middle is what I would like my menu to look like,
The image on the right is just a template to show you what I mean.

So basically the first UL will display, the second UL will display, in one row, then the third UL will be drawn just below the first UL, and then the fourth UL will be drawn below the second UL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
ul:nth-child(2n-1) {
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
}

ul:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-left: 150px; /* Or how many px you want */
}
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wmAUD/)</kbd>

Comment: This works, but what happens if a new list was added? or lets say I need to have it so we have 3 columns not 2 columns?

Comment: If more blocks are added it will be ok. If you need 3 columns, that's an entirely new question.

Comment: Well let's just say I need to expand the menu at a later date, and it would require there to be 4 columns? Or X amount of columns? Also how could I do this with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can try float left and float right, so

```
<ul class="columnLeft"> 1. ....</ul>
<ul class="columnRight"> 2. ....</ul>
<ul class="columnLeft"> 3. ....</ul>
<ul class="columnRight"> 4. ....</ul>
```

with stylesheet

```
columnLeft { float: left;}
columnRight { float: right;}
```

At your picture, the first UL and the second UL have different heights and the preceding ULs are directly sticked to the bottom of the upper one.
This is why you may create "columns" by classing-left/right.

Answer (score 0):

Or use this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4ePcW/)

```
<style>
.category-list{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
body {
    background-image: url("images/background.gif");
}

.red{
border: solid 1px red;
}
.green{
    border: solid 1px green;
}
.blue{
border: solid 1px blue;
}
.yellow{
border: solid 1px yellow;
}
.left{
    float: left;    
}
.right{
    float: right;    
}
</style>
<div class="category-list">
<div class="left">
    <ul class="red">
        <li>Item 1-1</li>
        <li>Item 1-2</li>
        <li>Item 1-3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="green">
        <li>Item 2-1</li>
        <li>Item 2-2</li>
        <li>Item 2-3</li>
        <li>Item 2-4</li>
        <li>Item 2-5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <ul class="blue">
        <li>Item 3-1</li>
        <li>Item 3-2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="yellow">
        <li>Item 4-1</li>
        <li>Item 4-2</li>
        <li>Item 4-3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly float your `<ul>`'s
give them a width e.g. `width: 50%;` for two columns, `width: 33%` for 3 columns
finally `clear` the outer div `category-list` so that your layout is maintained and doesn't messup the rest of the page.

here it is in its entirety:

```
.category-list:after{
    clear: both;
    display:block;
    content: '';
}

.category-list ul{
    float:left;
    width: 50%
}
```